# Apache - location header is ignore when using https

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I have site that use apaache as server.
The problem is that when I access page that redirects to external site (using `Location` header:

```
Location: https://www.google.pl
```

the url in location is replaced to domain root (ex. mydomain.com).
There is no such problem when accessing page without ssl.

Can be apache configured to behave like this?

EDIT:
redirection inside domain works fine - it seems that apache prevents only external url redirections.

**EDIT:**
To redirect I use simple php script:

```
header("Location: http://google.pl");
```

To sum up.

Over https:

`header("Location: http://google.com");` redirects to mydomain.com (I want to redirect it to google.com);

`header("Location: a");`redirects to mydomain.com/a

Over http:

`header("Location: http://google.com");` redirects to google.com

`header("Location: a");`redirects to mydomain.com/a

I have checked network traffic - when I use `header("Location: http://google.com");` over https, browsers gets "Location" header set to mydomain.com. It seems that it is overriden somewhere.

Comment: How are you actually doing this? In the apache config itself (Redirect / https://www.google.pl) or something else? And also, to be clear, the same redirect at the same location works when it's (a) internal or (b) to an external site using https, these aren't different redirects at different locations?

Comment: @Dave see my edit, please.

Comment: Are you sure your https virtual server is passing requests to PHP, and not doing some redirects on its own?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yeah - chceked that. Script is executed for sure.

Comment: What do the access logs show for the requests? Also do you have just the header line and then an exit() in the PHP script to avoid anything being re-written?

Comment: Does header("Location: a"); when you go to https://example.com redirect to https://example.com/a or http://example.com/a (e.g. does it drop the https? - if so that does point to some apache config moving from https to http).

Comment: It redirects to https.